# Alternar entre el operador = e IN de SQL en una consulta en Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Tengo un programa en Java que esta conectado a SQL-Server, y debe hacer un *select* a una tabla de empleados con un filtro de clave de empleado (String) en un *textfield* y el resultado lo envíe a un JTable. El problema está cuando quiero hacer búsqueda de mas de 1 empleado como se muestra abajo.

```
SELECT CODIGOEMPLEADO, NOMBRE FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE CODIGOEMPLEADO IN ('E1','E2', 'E3')
```

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer que la consulta se haga de maera dinámica `CODIGOEMPLEADO IN ('E1','E2', 'E3')` o `CODIGOEMPLEADO IN ('E1','E2', 'E3', 'E4')`

Hasta el momento he intentado lo siguiente:

```java
String Campo = jTextField1.getText();
String where;
if(!"".equals(Campo)) { 
    where = "WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO IN '"+ Campo+"'";
} else { 
    where = "WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO = '000'";
}

String xcConsulta = "select empleados.codigoempleado, empleados.apellidopaterno, empleados.apellidomaterno, empleados.nombre, empleados.cuentapagoelectronico, FROM EMPLEADOS + where;
```

En la variable campo se guardaría la cadena E1,E2,E3 y estos se pondrían en el *where* en lugar de ser `=` tenga el operador `in where = "WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO IN '"+ Campo+"'";`

Alguien que sea tan amable de apoyarme.

Comment: Agrega el código que has hecho por favor

Comment: String Campo = jTextField1.getText();
if(!"".equals(Campo))
        {
           where = "WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO = '"+ Campo+"'";
        }
          else 
        {
           where = "WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO = '000'"; 
        }

        String xcConsulta = "select empleados.codigoempleado, empleados.apellidopaterno, empleados.apellidomaterno, empleados.nombre, empleados.cuentapagoelectronico, "
                                + "FROM EMPLEADOS  "
                                + where;

Comment: En la variable campo se guardara la cadena E1,E2,E3 y estos ponerlos en el where  en lugar de ser = tenga el operador in   where = "WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO IN '"+ Campo+"'";

Comment: Hola Alfredo, puedes agregar el código como texto en la pregunta, utiliza el botón "Editar" que aparece debajo de las etiquetas, para que podamos entender mejor el código, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que entrecomillar cada valor.
La idea es:

1. Separar cada valor con `.split()`.
2. Eliminar espacios sobrantes, con ayuda de stream.
3. Juntar nuevamente los códigos, pero ahora entrecomillados.

```
String Campo = jTextField1.getText(); 
if(!"".equals(Campo)) {
   String codigos = Arrays.stream( Campo.split(",") ) // Separa por coma
                          .map( (str)-> str.trim() )  // Elimina espacios
                          .collect( Collectors.joining("','") ); // Une entrecomillado
   where = "WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO IN ('" + codigos + "')"; 
}
```

De tal manera que para la entrada `E1, E2,E3` resultado sería
`WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO IN ('E1','E2','E3')`

Answer (score 0):

Le falta los paréntesis a la parte del `IN`.

```
where = "WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO IN ("+ Campo+")"
```

La variable campo si es un String debe guardar "'E1,'E2','E3'".

Hay otros fallos en el string de la query como la coma al final en `empleados.cuentapagoelectronico` y el `+ where`  que debería estar fuera de las comillas dobles dejando la variable de la siguiente manera

```
String xcConsulta = "select empleados.codigoempleado, empleados.apellidopaterno, empleados.apellidomaterno, empleados.nombre, empleados.cuentapagoelectronico FROM EMPLEADOS" + where;
```

La traducción final de la query quedaría así:

```
select empleados.codigoempleado, empleados.apellidopaterno, empleados.apellidomaterno, empleados.nombre, empleados.cuentapagoelectronico FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE EMPLEADOS.CODIGOEMPLEADO IN ('E1,'E2','E3');
```

Comment: Asi es.... el tema que esta tomando el valor Campo = jTextField1.getText(); en este si me mando 'E1,E2,E3' no esta correcto. mi pregunta, ese query como le puedo pasa ese parametro. mandaria  'E1,E2,E3' y java lo tiene que intepretar ('E1,'E2','E3'); actualmente recibe ('E1, E2, E3');

Comment: Una solución seria separar el String en un array de esta manera `String[] campoSeparado = campo.split(",")`. Una vez separado los valores, recorrer el array con un for y reconstruir el String con el formato "'valor1','valor2'..."